# Is reference ID same as address of a memory location in java?

Tags: java, memory, addressing

In Computer, variables are either accessed by **name** or the **memory location**. So is **reference ID** in java same as **memory address**?

Comment: So what do you mean with "reference ID"?

Comment: This diagram may be helpful for your understanding [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZNqUJ5-X3CbeYXMDkBr0H2u2Svh19viK/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

No. Memory addresses are usually represented by something like 'Fx012450001235' that will reference a starting point in the computer memory.

When Java prints to you something like 'ObjectClass@a2saA', that is some form of object index of the current JVM thread, not the memory address of the object you are using.